# Relocation vs travel?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, close-reasons

Pretty obviously relocation from one country to another at some point requires physical travel.

Which aspects related to relocation should be considered off-topic here, as they should rather be asked on [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)? Which would be on-topic?

Answer (score 9):

I asked [this question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/964/how-to-book-flights-when-moving-to-another-country) which is about relocation. I am of the opinion that this does belong here for the following reasons:

- Relocation is very different from travel, as it's usually one-way and long term.
- Problems linked to relocation are bound to affect every expat at some point and are thus highly relevant to this site

As I stated in the question comments, this is IMO no travel.SE question as it's for long term and would thus probably be closed there.

I wanted to ask some more questions along those lines, so I guess it's a good thing if we get this sorted out.

Comment: There are many questions on Travel.SE about one-way airfare, about open-ended return dates, and in fact, about every aspect of that question. :)

Comment: @Flimzy: You're absolutely right, but I think it's more question about how SE should work in general. Should you always go to other site where the question is "more on-topic" or should there be some overlap. In case for example for StackOverflow it's the latter. SO has tons of questions, considered on-topic, which could as well go to ServerFault, Programmers.SE, AskUbuntu, Unix&Linux etc.

Comment: @vartec: The vast majority of questions on SO that are on topic on any of those other sites pre-date the other sites. Any new Ubuntu questions are migrated/closed almost immediately.

Comment: In this particular case, the question doesn't seem especially off-topic at first blush, but if I were to write an answer, it would be full of links to Travel.SE answers.  This is what makes me think it should be a Travel.SE question.

Comment: @Flimzy: which isn't necessarily a bad thing. Someone looking for information regarding relocation might come here not even knowing of existence of Travel.SE.